# save dataframe values to txt file

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

so i wanna save this dataframe into a text file:

```
print(myDF)
             0         1         2         3         4
away       0.0  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.051917
g          0.0  0.000000  0.051093  0.000000  0.000000
attract    0.0  0.000000  0.025547  0.000000  0.000000
might      0.0  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.051917
working    0.0  0.000000  0.025547  0.000000  0.000000
...        ...       ...       ...       ...       ...
stuck      0.0  0.089413  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
bit        0.0  0.000000  0.025547  0.000000  0.000000
```

To a similar way, each value separeted by space and each line separeted by '\n' (jumpline)

```
0.0  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.051917
0.0  0.000000  0.051093  0.000000  0.000000
0.0  0.000000  0.025547  0.000000  0.000000
0.0  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.051917
0.0  0.000000  0.025547  0.000000  0.000000
0.0  0.089413  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
0.0  0.000000  0.025547  0.000000  0.000000
```

Comment: What have you tried so far based on your own research, and what went wrong with your attempts? For example, `to_csv()` or `to_string()`?

Comment: i didn't try anything yet because i though if i will save it the way it is the headlines will stay for exemple ; away g attract....  and i didnt know a straight up way to do it

Comment: the answer bellow made the job done, thank's for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `to_csv` like this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'product_name': ['laptop', 'printer', 'tablet', 'desk', 'chair'],
        'price': [1200, 150, 300, 450, 200]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.to_csv(r'pandas.txt', header=None, index=None, sep=' ', mode='a')
```

Output:

```
laptop 1200
printer 150
tablet 300
desk 450
chair 200
```

Comment: that answer made the thing done, thank's for your help